# Problema con valores Rich Snippets en Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

Hemos creado una tienda online en Angular 1, en las fichas de los productos hemos colocado las etiquetas rich snippets de  schema.org para ayudar a mejorar el SEO y las vistas de nuestra web.

El problema con el que nos encontramos, es que, utilizando la herramienta de Google de testeo de microdatos (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), al poner una URL de nuestra ficha, la herramienta no encuentra ningún valor en los microdatos.

URL: https://www.viladomat.com/fitxaesport/354023/ES/es_ES/1/1/0/9/141/127/0/0/1221/1/0/0/rush+short+m/la+sportiva

Encuentra correctamente las etiquetas pero los valores, al ser dinámicos en angular, no los encuentra.
Hemos probado tanto de poner las etiquetas dinámicas dentro del cuerpo de la página, como en un script en el Header, y no encuentra ningún tipo de valor.
Alguien se ha encontrado con este problema?
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!